# Why am I seeing "Starting snappy daemon [ok] " before Ubuntu login

Tags: snap

I started to see the text "Starting snappy daemon [ok] " after I start my computer, and before the login loads.

This text is not always displayed.

Also, I ran the command "sudo systemctl status snap*", and although I did not installed anything related to snappy, the output is:

```
    ● snapd.refresh.timer - Timer to automatically refresh installed snaps
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.refresh.timer; enabled; vendor pres
   Active: active (waiting) since Tue 2017-10-03 05:16:34 PDT; 7min ago

Oct 03 05:16:34 hpe systemd[1]: Started Timer to automatically refresh installed

● snapd.socket - Socket activation for snappy daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.socket; enabled; vendor preset: ena
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-10-03 05:16:34 PDT; 7min ago
   Listen: /run/snapd.socket (Stream)
           /run/snapd-snap.socket (Stream)

Oct 03 05:16:34 hpe systemd[1]: Starting Socket activation for snappy daemon.
Oct 03 05:16:34 hpe systemd[1]: Listening on Socket activation for snappy daemon

● snap-repair.timer - Timer to automatically fetch and run repair assertions
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snap-repair.timer; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: active (waiting) since Tue 2017-10-03 05:16:34 PDT; 7min ago

Oct 03 05:16:34 hpe systemd[1]: Started Timer to automatically fetch and run rep

● snapd.service - Snappy daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
lines 1-23...skipping...
● snapd.refresh.timer - Timer to automatically refresh installed snaps
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.refresh.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (waiting) since Tue 2017-10-03 05:16:34 PDT; 7min ago

Oct 03 05:16:34 hpe systemd[1]: Started Timer to automatically refresh installed snaps.

● snapd.socket - Socket activation for snappy daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-10-03 05:16:34 PDT; 7min ago
   Listen: /run/snapd.socket (Stream)
           /run/snapd-snap.socket (Stream)

Oct 03 05:16:34 hpe systemd[1]: Starting Socket activation for snappy daemon.
Oct 03 05:16:34 hpe systemd[1]: Listening on Socket activation for snappy daemon.

● snap-repair.timer - Timer to automatically fetch and run repair assertions
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snap-repair.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (waiting) since Tue 2017-10-03 05:16:34 PDT; 7min ago

Oct 03 05:16:34 hpe systemd[1]: Started Timer to automatically fetch and run repair assertions.

● snapd.service - Snappy daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-10-03 05:16:39 PDT; 7min ago
 Main PID: 1160 (snapd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/snapd.service
           └─1160 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd

Oct 03 05:16:34 hpe systemd[1]: Starting Snappy daemon...
Oct 03 05:16:38 hpe snapd[1160]: 2017/10/03 05:16:38.072701 daemon.go:252: started snapd/2.27.5 (seri
    Oct 03 0

5:16:39 hpe systemd[1]: Started Snappy daemon.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `snapd` package is installed by default, in 16.04 and newer. It would therefore be started and running by default as well.

If you are not using any snap installed packages, it should be totally fine to remove the `snapd` package from the system.

Comment: Why I did not see the text "Starting snappy daemon [ok] "  before, and today I started to see it?

Comment: I can't answer that. There's a million possible explanations for that, and even now you're saying you don't see it every time. So maybe you installed something else which introduced a possible i/o hit, causing a delay, which results in sometimes the text being visible before plymouth can display the graphical boot, or before Xorg comes up.

Comment: Thank you dobey. The most "sophisticated" software I am using, is LAMP. Can I safely uninstall snappy?

Comment: I have uninstalled `snapd` on several 16.04 systems without any problem.  Since I don't use snaps, it seemed to be an un-necessary use of resources (from the logs, it was often calling home to check for updates).

Answer (score 1):

Note that snapd should not be permanently running if no snaps are used, it is socket activated ...  the systemd unit that prints the "Starting snappy daemon [ok]" only sets up the socket through which snapd will be started once you use the snap command.